# I would like to: switch to Finder via Cmd-Tab and a new Finder window does not open

Tags: finder

When I switch to Finder using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and there are no Finder windows open already, a new Finder window opens up.

How can I have that **not** happen?

FYI: I am on Ventura 13.6.1 and on a 16-inch MBP (2021)

Based on the comments I wonder if it is the app Contexts that is responsible...

Comment: What do you plan to do in Finder without any windows?

Comment: @benwiggy It's an anal retentive thing - just to see the clean desktop when I "reset" my mind from one task to another - I know, it makes no practical sense...

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I am using the application [Contexts](https://contexts.co/) for switching through the different running apps. As soon as I quit it, the behavior stopped.